# How to modify a file content in browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, blob, unzip

I have a fileList having files of different types. looking for a way by which i can modify a specific file content and save the modified files in some variable by JavaScript.

I want to do everything by JavaScript.

Comment: you want to modify server side files or local files ?

Comment: i want to modify server side files in javascript (browser) and after editing again posting it to server